# wordpress 404 error when trying to acess folder on root

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website and within the root directory a folder called /ideal/.

The function for the /ideal/ folder is to make payments trough the website from visitors.

Everything worked well for a while, since a few days there is a problem with the page.

When i navigate to my website http://www.nibincasso.nl/ideal/ it wil show up with a 404 error.

With the release of wordpress 4.0 it looks like wordpress is trying to make some sort of dynamic link for the folder /ideal/.

However i want it to open as a static page, not by making it a wordpress dynamic page. “http://www.nibincasso.nl/ideal/index.php”.

Example of .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can someone help me with a solution for this problem?

Kind regards,

Fabi

Update *

I created a new subdirectory on my root with a blank index.php page only saying test
This one opens fine. But when i try to enter the subdirectory /ideal/ with the index.php i get a 404 error. How come?

Comment: maybe its a htaccess problem. Could you post it?

Comment: Hi o Pi, Look at the thread i edited the question with the .htaccess

Comment: it seems to be ok. Are you sure youre writing the correct folder name?

Comment: Hi o Pi, yes the strange thing is it always worked well since some new updates from wordpress.

It looks like wordpress is making it to a dynamic page.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ideal/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ideal/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Dear Bhumi, no luck this result in a Internal Server Error.

Comment: have you change your database urls?

Comment: for wordpress settings i use: Siteadres (URL): http://www.nibincasso.nl and WordPress-adres (URL): http://www.nibincasso.nl do i need to change this?

Comment: I pasted the code above in my htaccess and my siteadres (url) and wordpress-adres (url) are as follow: h t t p : // w w w dot nibincasso dot nl. is there anything else i need to change?

Comment: Dear @Bhumi Shah,
The url for the website nibincasso.nl need to stay the same.
/ideal/ need to be a static subpage not the main url for the website.

Comment: It still looks like wordpress is trying to open the subfolder "ideal" as a wordpress page. any solutions left?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the php code inside the index from the /ideal/ folder.
I will search for the solution this is not a wordpress problem.

Thanks for helping me for so far.

Comment: could you solve it? I need to put a folder with some pdf files in the root in order to legacy content be linked appropriately. And I´m getting the 404 error you described